# Knockout Checkbox List Visibility and Value Control

Tags: knockout.js, data-binding

My form has a list of groups that a user may sign up for. Some of these groups contain subgroups that the user may also sign up for. I would like to use Knockout JS to control the visibility of the subgroups' checkboxes to only be visible when the meta-group is checked. I accomplished this using the `visible` binding. However, I need to be able to read the value of the checkbox as well, and I'm running into some issues with multiple-binding across models.

The general structure of my checkboxes is:

```
<div id="CheckBoxArray">
  <input type='checkbox' value='Group1' id='chkboxGroup1' data-bind='checked: Group1SubsVisible'/>
    <div id=Group1SubGroups data-bind='visible: Group1SubsVisible'/>
      <input type='checkbox' value='SubGroup1'/>
      ...
    </div>
    ...
</div>

<script>
  function VisibilityModel(){
    this.Group1Visible = ko.observable(false);
    ...
  }

  function ApplicantModel(){
    this.FirstName = ko.observable();
    ...
    this.CheckedGroups = ko.observableArray();
  }
</script>
```

I've omitted extraneous information and repetitious elements.

The issue I'm having is that when I change the meta-group data-bindings to attempt to capture their value as well as control visibility, the sub-groups never become visible.

```
<input type='checkbox' value='Group1' id='chkboxGroup1' data-bind='checked: Group1SubsVisible, checked: CheckedGroups'/>
```

Inspecting the model in the console reports that the last value of the "visible" variable is false. 
I initially thought the issue would be related to having two models in the same scope, so I split the `ko.applyBindings` for each model to look at separate divs, and moved the `CheckedGroups` into the VisibilityModel. This had no effect on my issue, so I've reverted it to the original code here.

Comment: `data-bind='checked: Group1SubsVisible, checked: CheckedGroups'` Two checked bindings?! Did you mean to use `visible` there?

Comment: No, that's intentional. The two bindings should be on different models. I'd like to have one binding update a variable to control visibility of other checkboxes, and another binding add the value of the checkbox to the list of checked boxes. Is that not possible using bindings alone?

Comment: Nope. I don't think it is allowed.

Comment: Ah, that's a shame. I'll have to do it using some sort of callback then. I had a feeling that overlapping bindings from separate models might be a problem. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a boolean property for `visible` binding, you can use the [`indexOf`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html#indexof) method to check whether a `group`'s value exists in the `CheckedGroups` array:

```
<input type='checkbox' value='Group1' id='chkboxGroup1' data-bind='checked: CheckedGroups' /> 
Group1
<div id="Group1SubGroups" data-bind="visible: CheckedGroups.indexOf('Group1') > -1">
  <input type='checkbox' value='SubGroup1'/> Group1 Sub 1
</div>

<input type='checkbox' value='Group2' id='chkboxGroup2' data-bind='checked: CheckedGroups' /> 
Group2
<div id="Group1SubGroups" data-bind="visible: CheckedGroups.indexOf('Group2') > -1">
  <input type='checkbox' value='SubGroup1'/> Group2 Sub 1
</div>
```

And in your view model:

```
var viewModel = function() {
   var self = this;
   self.CheckedGroups = ko.observableArray(["Group1", "Group3"])
}
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/0mkg6wn5/2/)

Comment: This did resolve my issue, actually. Thank you for the help!